# PHP: Error on un-initialized class member / property

Tags: php

It seems to me that PHP class members are less strict than variables, even on the strictest error reporting.
For instance

```
class A
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->test = 0;
    }
}

$a = new A();
```

does not give an error in any case. I would like to manually define $test (as public/protected/private). Sure i could define __get($field) and __set($field) but I'm looking for a global solution.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature. Give [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-flexobj/) a thorough read.

Comment: You could emulate active record pattern having __get and __set methods and operate on an internal array, which is what happens in your linked article. I guess my suggestion would be that in a lack of get and set magic methods, it defers to an error instead of auto-initialization (like call does). There is no contradictions between my suggestion and that article, although it would probably break a lot of code.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
class A
{
    private  $test;

    public function __construct( $test = 0 ) // set a default value to 0 if no parameters

    {

        $this->test = $test;



    }

    public function __set( $field  )

    {
        if( isset( $field ) === true )

        {  
            $this->test = $field;
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
    public function __get()

    {

        return $this->test;

    }

}
 $a = new A();

 echo $a->get();
?>
```

Comment: Well, I noted I was not looking for a __get/__set hack.